# Writing finite sets of positive integers as sets of positive values of a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

This question came to me after answering [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350089/) about Diophantine sets over at MathOverflow. (It may strike the reader as frivolous, but there you go.) Prompted by this question I started wondering if there were interesting Diophantine subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ for which one could write down relatively simple polynomials $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that the set of positive values of $f$ equals $A$ (i.e. $f(\mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{N}_{>0} = A$). It occurred to me that I should start by asking about *finite* Diophantine sets.

I then found that yes, it is easy to do this: for finite sets $A$ of positive integers, the following polynomial
$$
f = X \left( 1 - X \cdot \prod_{a \in A} (X - a)^2 \right)
$$
takes the value $x$ at $X=x$ if $x \in A$, and is negative if $x \notin A$. (**Proof.** If $x>0$ and we let $X=x$ in the expression for $f$, then clearly the second factor in the expression is non-positive, except if $x \in A$, when it equals unity. If $x \leq 0$ on the other hand, then it is clearly positive. Combining the conclusions from both cases, the product comes out negative or zero if $x \notin A$, and as $x$ when $x \in A$.)

So if $A$ has $n$ elements, this gives us a degree $2n+2$ polynomial $f$ such that the set of positive values of $f$ equals $A$. Since I like to be economical in the construction of my polynomials (parsimony is a virtue after all), I wonder whether this number is in fact the best we can do.

> For each $n$, do we need a degree $2n+2$ polynomial in general to represent an $n$-element set $A$ of positive integers in the above manner? Put more precisely, for each $n$ does there exist an $n$-element set $A$ of positive integers such that $A$ is not the set of positive values of $f$ for any polynomial $f$ of degree $\leq 2n+1$?

Comment: For $n\le2$, we can find a polynomial of degree $2n$ where the positive values are the local extrema. (For instance, if $A=\{r,s\}$ with $s>r$, then I think $-rx^4+(8r-2s)x^3+(9s-22r)x^2+(24r-12s)x+5s-8r$ works.) But it looks to me like this can't be done in general for $n=3$, so that if there's a general construction for degree $2n$ (or $2n+1$), it's not straightforward.

Comment: You're right! I think we can even manage with degree $2$, because if we take $f = p + bx + (q - p - b)x^2$, we have $f(0) = p$ and $f(1)=q$, and we still have the freedom of choice for $b$ to ensure that $f(-1)$ and $f(2)$ are negative, which ensures that $f(x)$ is negative outside $\{0,1\}$. Indeed, $f(-1)=q-2b$ and $f(2)=4q-3p-2b$, so for $b$ large enough we find an $f$ that accomplishes our goal.

Comment: In any case, $f$ needs to be of even degree, since an odd degree polynomial with integral coefficients will always take an infinite number of positive values on the integers (since the leading term will dominate for sufficiently large arguments).